# Как дизассемблировать c# приложение

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-cli

Используя ReflectionDisassembler, можно получить IL код приложения. Можно ли получить c# код приложения, без использования сторонних библиотек?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "без использования сторонних библиотек"? Вам нужно получить исходный код с помощью самописного приложения на C#? Если да - бог в помощь. Если нет - ILSpy в помощь

Comment: https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy изучаете код, пишете свой собственный по образу и подобию.

Comment: если установлен .NET Framework, то можно использовать `ildasm.exe`.